# Nodejs + express - Unexplained Memory leaks on Kubernetes architecture

Tags: node.js, express, kubernetes

I'm facing unexplained memory consumptions increase on some pods on my Kubernetes cluster.

It's a Node + Express.js app with a high amount of transactions.

Pod memory consumptions can remain low (80 Mi for instance) for days, and without any particular reasons (maybe a traffic increase, but nothing incredible...), the memory consumptions skyrockets to 1000 Mi which causes pod failure.
I've tried to look for memory leaks but was not able to find anything. I'm although monitoring errors in pod to pod connections, those leaks can happen even without any errors in such connections.

Any suggestions ? Is there an exponential link between number of connections and memory consumption?

Thanks,

Comment: try something like New Relic, it helps monitor the whole app. You will find many helpful information such as transaction, request, throughput... Those will help you identify the issue

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.